# Returning Future of Future in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

In the code below I have to return the result of a future that is invoked after another future. I'm getting the following error in the `future2.map` line:

> type mismatch; found : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
>   required: play.api.mvc.Result

How to make this work?

```
def method1 = Action.async { request => 
    val future1 = f1
    future1.map { result1 =>
          val future2 = f2
          future2.map { result2 =>
              Ok(result1+result2+"")
          }
    }
}

def f1 = Future { 1 }
def f2 = Future { 2 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this in many ways. But first, you need to understand how `map` and `flatMap` work with `Future`:

```
def map[S](f: (T) ⇒ S): Future[S]
def map[S](f: (T) ⇒ Future[S]): Future[Future[S]]
def flatMap[S](f: (T) ⇒ Future[S]): Future[S]
```

*Note that,in above signatures, you are calling `map` and `flatMap` with a value that `already is a future` i.e `Future[<some-value>].map(...)` or `Future[<some-value>].flatMap(...)`.*

**Approach 1:**

```
    def method1 = Action.async { request =>
    val future1 = f1
    future1.flatMap { result1 => //replaced map with flatMap
      val future2 = f2
      future2.map { result2 =>
        Ok(result1+result2+"")
      }
    }
  }

  def f1 = Future { 1 }
  def f2 = Future { 2 }
```

**Approach 2:**

```
def method1 = Action.async { request =>
    val future1 = f1
    future1.flatMap { result1 => //replaced map with flatMap
      val future2 = f2
      future2.flatMap { result2 => //replaced map with flatMap
        Future.successful{Ok(result1+result2+"")} // used Future.successful{} to generate a Future of Result
      }
    }
  }

  def f1 = Future { 1 }
  def f2 = Future { 2 }
```

Comment: Approach 2 adds an unnecessary layer of complexity by surrounding the result in a successful `Future`. Although you _can_ do it, there's absolutely no reason to prefer that one over the first.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was trying to illustrate different ways how `map` and `flatMap` work with future.And `Future.successful()` is inevitable when we have to handle multiple cases inside future computations where one case returns a `Future(value)` and the other case returns `value` only.

Answer (score 3):

Changing `future1.map` to `future1.flatMap` should do the trick. Mapping over a `Future` returns another `Future` and changes the value inside. In this case, you're returning a `Future` that contains *another* `Future` that contains a `Result`. By using `flatMap`, it essentially flattens the nested `Future[Future[Result]]` into a `Future[Result]`.